# Saying "gate 'ooks" instead of "gateaux"

Tags: dialects

My father-in-law will say "gate 'ooks" instead of "gateaux". He claims this is a regional/dialectal thing and that it was common in the part of Sussex where he grew up.

Is that likely, or is it more plausible that it was just him and a few of his friends mocking the spelling? My googling can find nothing useful on the subject.

Comment: I am American, so please forgive my butting in. I had a friend growing up who would say, "mercy buck-ups" for Merçi beaucoup". Your question reminded me of her.

Comment: @medica My childhood friend said "Mercy buckets!"

Comment: I haven't heard of ending a meal with "gate 'ooks" only of starting one with "horse doovers".

Comment: Is he the librarian at Unseen University?

Comment: I'm from rural Sussex. I can certainly imagine older natives of Sussex saying this, with the Sussex accent, but I've never actually heard it (so this is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: It's a manner of pronouncing or an accent.

Comment: I've researched in the 'general dictionary of provincialisms', and 'A glossary of the provincialisms in use in the county of Sussex' and found nothing but it may be in a later book

Answer (score 2):

I believe that 'gateaux' is the original French - so if using the word, the only real pronunciation would be 'Gatt-oh' in the same style as the native use. 'Gat-ooks' seems like some sort of niche corruption of the original, which is probably only valid within his certain circle rather than the wider (correct) use of 'Gateaux' (presumably without accent - throwing in a French accent on a single word in an otherwise English sentence has always seemed like an unusual idea to me).

Answer (score 0):

There is no official pronunciation of local dialect that matches what you report. The local terminology for that is 'taking the piss'.

It's simply old people trying to be clever. All the rest of the jokes they could make are either racist or vulgar or both.

Comment: "local terminology": local to where?